# Why is the sump pump inlet draining directly onto the float?

Tags: basement, pump, sump-pump

Why is the sump pump inlet draining directly onto the float?  Won't this prevent it from rising most of the time?

Comment: Perhaps a picture would help.  I have no idea what you're describing.  Since you have a low rep, just upload it to imgur.com and put the link in a comment and someone will edit it into your question.

Comment: Photo, please? The sump pump's inlet should be at the bottom of the pump, well below the float, and it's output should be through a check valve to a pipe or hose that sends the water somewhere else. There shouldn't be any mechanical interference with the float, and it shouldn't be "draining onto" anything.

Comment: ... or do you mean that the sump inlet is aligned with the pump's float? If so, there usually won't be a strong enough stream of water coming in for this to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Totally not a problem - if it was a problem, the sump would be overflowing and you'd be asking about the flood.

The force of a stream of water coming in from a side pipe to a sump is quite minor compared with the force of the collected water pushing up on the float.

Assume that it DID affect operation - once the water had risen to the level of the pipe, the incoming water would be flowing straight in OVER the float, and the float would not be affected. But I bet it never even gets close to that point, in reality.

If you like, take a 5 gallon bucket or a hose and dump/run water directly onto the float and watch what actually happens.